# What is best practice from verifying many fields in cucumber/Gherkin?

Tags: bdd, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, acceptance-testing, atdd

What is the best practice for verifying a REST response that contains multiple relevant fields in cucmber/Gherkin?  We are using scenario outlines so things are parameterized with examples tables.

Here are some approaches I've considered:

Simplest approach would be to just add each field as a column in the examples table.  But this quickly became very unreadable as the examples table overflowed the width of the screen and we ended up with a almost a dozen steps in each scenario of the form: `And the <fieldName> should be <value>`.  This is very verbose and obviously departs from the spirit of Gherkin being intended to resemble natural language.

Next I considered putting the response body as a whole into a file in JSON format and verifying it in a single step like `And the response matches <file containing expected response>`(examples table would just contain the path to the file).  However, this makes it very opaque exactly what I am verifying in the test as the actual fields and data values are hidden away in another file.  Furthemore, I've read that test steps should not be concerned with the exact format of the data (JSON, XML, or whatever).

After that I read [this article](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/integration-testing-your-http-api-with-cucumber) uses a vertical table after the step to specify multiple fields.  Resulting in something like this:

```
And the response contains:
| field1 | value1 |
| field2 | value2 |
```

However, I was unsure of how to parameterize this.  Individual atomic values go into a column in the examples table but what about a whole other table?  I looked into whether nested tables are supported but it seems like some people believe that to be [unreadable and bad practice as well](https://joebuschmann.com/specflow-nested-tables-a-bad-idea/).

So, what is the general best practice for this scenario?  For a parameterized scenario, what approach strikes the best balance between natural-language readability and precisely conveying your expectations?

Comment: Are you sure you should use Cucumber for this? This isn't sound like you are testing business rules. You may be better of with other tools more suited to testing an API contract. (Think spring integration test, or spring cloud contracts).

Comment: What makes you think it's not testing business rules?

Comment: You're talking about fields and responses. And referencing responses stored in other files. The language you're using isn't business language. It is technical. An example of a business language would be: Given a C-type loan And a yearly interest rate of 5.21%. When the principle is paid within one month. Then the customer is flagged for immediate review.

Comment: fields in the response are dictated by business rules, no?  I am using technical language.  But that is because I am asking about how to implement such a test, not necessarily the wording I will use to describe it.

Comment: Or are you saying APIs in general are too modular to test with Cucumber?

Comment: To use your example: Given a C-type loan And a yearly interest rate of 5.21%. When the principle is paid within one month. Then immediate review is recommended AND _.  Where _ is some other result that business also cares about but cannot be folded into "immediate review".  How to write a scenario for that?

Comment: The response and the fields in it are implementation details. Try to describe your feature without them.  https://cucumber.io/blog/2015/03/24/single-source-of-truth https://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-better-cucumber-scenarios-or-why-were

Usually a few And ... statements don't hurt. Can you give an example of such a result where it does become a problem that isn't also describing the implementation?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what qualifies as "implementation details".  In your first link, it could be argued that allowing the customer the option to go back as well as not allowing them to edit a particular value ARE business rules(it certainly qualifies as behavior).  The argument of the post seems to be less that those things are "implementation details" and more that UI elements are better tested somewhere else.

Comment: For my example, the current scenarios look roughly like this:
Given <some inputs>\ 
When the api is called\
Then there <should be/should not be> a concern for: <X>\
And there <should be/should not be> a concern for: <X>\
And there <should be/should not be> a concern for: <X>\
...\

<X> here denotes a type of fraud/risk assessment.  There are a bunch of types for X resulting the long list of "And"s.

Comment: You can make that argument but if you make that argument it also means you can't write your gherkin in a clear fashion. If you can express all those clauses in a single clause you can push down the checks to the implementation of that step. Otherwise, they are perhaps different scenarios?